# Pandas combine multiple column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of survey data that contain > 100 columns and most of them are duplicated column name with different Value

[image]

My objective is to create a code to group all column that have the same column name automatically no matter how many column inside my file as per sample below :

[image]

Ive tried ffill however I cant find a way to make sure that my ffill stop if the column name are different
Can anybody please teach me on how to do this?

Thank You
Best Regards
Railey Shahril

Answer (score 1):

If possible multiple values per groups and need only last non misisng values use:

Idea is grouping by duplicated columns names, forward filling missing values and select last column per groups in lambda function:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
```

---

If there is only one non missing row per group and need last one:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).last()
```

Comment: `first` and `last` behave weird with strings. They will return `None`. Be careful with copying other answers without testing! :)

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - hmmm, I test it with numbers, but now I test it with strings

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - `df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,4],
         'B':[3, 4,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan],
         'D':[1,3,np.nan,7,1,0],
         'E':[np.nan,3,6,9,2,4],
         'r':[1,3,np.nan,7,1,0],
})
df.columns = list('AABBB')`

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - Do you have experience `They will return None` ? If yes, then better is first solution,

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([[None, 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Group 1'], ['Kuala Lumpur', None, 'Group 1']], columns=['Place', 'Place', 'Group']).groupby(level=0, axis=1).last()`

Comment: `first` gives me `None, 'Kuala Lumpur'`, `last` gives me `'Kuala Lumpur', None`

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - But in sample data are `NaN`s, hmmm

Comment: If i use `None, 1` it does work, using `None, 'str'` it does not, hmmmm

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - hmmm, if problem wit secons solution , I thinkfist should workin gnice